# What commands in Stata are directly compiled from C?

Tags: stata

The answer would be helpful in identifying the bottlenecks in the code.

Inspired by this (URL updated): http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2012-03/msg01181.html

On Mon, Mar 26, 2012 at 8:10 PM, Nick Cox  wrote:
>

> -tabulate- is a built-in command, namely compiled C code. If you want
>   to look at the code, you will need to get a developer's job at
>   StataCorp, but that in essence is why it is fast.
>
> -collapse- by contrast is lots of Stata code to interpret. You can
>   look at it in any text editor. including -doedit-.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you type

```
which foo
```

where `foo` is the command you are interested in, then you will be told whether `foo` is defined by an ado file, which will be named, or is "built-in". The latter is compiled code.

But the nature of Stata is such that this is not an absolute distinction. Ultimately, each command defined by an ado file is based on commands that are built-in.

Comment: Thanks Nick! How then is one able to identify bottlenecks? Perhaps, there is a list of slow commands?

Comment: I would be grateful if you could answer

Comment: There is no list of slow commands in Stata that I know of. How could there be? Some commands will be slow for you depending on what you want of them, your dataset size, how difficult it is to fit a model your computer set-up, etc. You find out what is slow for you by trying it. See also further comments above.

Comment: It would be ideal for me as a user to figure out whether I could somehow speed up my code, right?.. this is just a wish :)

Comment: Sure, but there is not an easy short answer on what is slow. Looping over observations is very slow; that's a start.

Comment: I do not necessarily need an easy answer but the question I am asking seems very relevant in many contexts/languages. And I am surprised how small the published evidence is on what is slow w.r.t. Stata environment. Perhaps, I should just post some code here and ask whether it could be sped up..

Comment: Again, no dispute that people want to know this, but that is absolutely not the point: it would be a lot of work for experienced Stata programmers to write a really good answer. People who answer questions have other things they want to do too. As you say, specific code will be most likely to attract helpful specific comments.